# How to use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

When I use dplyr's `pivot_wider` and there are not uniquely identified rows, I get the following error:

```
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates
```

I'm interested in the summary of duplicates, but when I set `values_fn = summary_fun` or `values_fun = {summary_fun}` it throws an error.  How do I actually summarize duplicates in the way intended by the values_fn parameter?

Comment: `{summary_fun}` I think is a placeholder for the function to be applied. The general syntax to use `values_fn` is `values_fn = list(col_name = function_name)`.

Comment: Ah, I gotcha.  Do you have any idea what that function would look like to summarize duplicates?

Comment: Depending on your requirement, you can use any function like `sum`, `mean`.  See the example in `?pivot_wider` `warpbreaks %>% pivot_wider(names_from = wool, values_from = breaks,values_fn = list(breaks = mean))`

Comment: Ah, I see.  I just wanted to identify which rows were the duplicates (e.g. which ones are summarized via list-cols.  Now I understand.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The commonly used R summary functions {summary_fun} are: mean, max, min, median, sum, prod. Some dplyr functions also work: first, last.

You can also use an anonymous function in values_fn for more flexibility.  See example:

```
   warpbreaks %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = wool, 
               values_from = breaks,
               values_fn = function(x) paste(x, collapse=","))
```

Or to summarize a test of the contents:

```
  warpbreaks %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = wool, 
              values_from = breaks,
              values_fn =  function(x) paste("Any over 40:", any(x>40)))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  tension A                  B                 
  <fct>   <chr>              <chr>             
1 L       Any over 40: TRUE  Any over 40: TRUE 
2 M       Any over 40: FALSE Any over 40: TRUE 
3 H       Any over 40: TRUE  Any over 40: FALSE
```